# Win10 Command Prompt as "System" loads out of session

Tags: windows-10, command-line, console

We're trying to launch a command prompt in Windows 10 as the System user. We have in our environment some security policies and AV (McAfee). The end result is to run an MSI uninstaller as the "System" user in order to run an uninstall (and possibly do a fresh install) of some deeply rooted software.

Without McAfee installed (did a reformat) PSExec will launch from an Elevated Command Prompt (only - "Access Denied" for other "admin" users), and will launch an interactive command prompt as the System user (verified with WhoAmI). Once McAfee is installed, PSExec is no longer allowed to run with "-s".

We've tried using the well-known:

```
sc create cmdsvc binpath= “cmd /K start” type= own type= interact
```

This launches a console window as the "system" account (verified in Task Manager), but does not show in the current user session. I'm guessing that it's in some "background" "system account" session(???). When McAfee is installed, we get a prompt about the "Interactive Services Detection" (yes, in Windows 10, with or without the "NoInteractiveServices" set to O), whereupon selecting "View the message" gives two black console screens that can't be interacted with, and that disappear after about two minutes (keyboard is disabled, mouse is disabled, two minutes appears to be the "timeout" limit).

With McAfee, we can use that SC command to run a batch script under the System context, but it's (again) in the background and only does so much: we've gotten it load an MSI via the bat commands, but it hangs there and runs in the (invisible) background session, and we've gotten it to echo output to a text file (such as "whoami") that shows up when it's done.

We're trying to get it to show in the current user session, as trying to run MSI just hangs and we don't know what it's asking for. We'd like to get to a spot where we can have an interactive "system" console (command) window. Running the MSI uninstaller and logging what's going on would be good, too. Just guessing at MSI switches so far hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Running interactive console as system account is rather tricky. I suggest you to use special tools to simplify the process.

#### [psexec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

This tool from Microsoft sysinternals allows this to do as simple as

```
psexec.exe -i -s -d cmd.exe
```

#### [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)

This terminal (I'm the author) allows you to use tabs and panes to organize your consoles, which may be run (in the one terminal window) under active or specified user, elevated, system, or limited account. It's very configurable and there are [many ways to run consoles](https://conemu.github.io/en/LaunchNewTab.html). Most simple way is run from <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

```
ConEmu64.exe -run cmd -new_console:aA
```